# Chinese for "patch" in the sense of "software patch"

Tags: word-requests

The [dictionary](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=patch) lists many words for "patch" but none that explicitly state they mean patch in the software sense of the word.

EDIT: Dictionary has now been updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's 补丁. Like the English word "patch", this word can also mean "a piece of cloth used to cover holes in clothes when they get worn".

Comment: Quite simple... :D

Comment: coool.. i'll submit an update for CC-CEDICT